# Enter date in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm entering tons of dates into Excel - all for the same month and year just different days. Is it possible to simply enter "20" into a cell and have it populate as "12/20/2013" ?

Answer (score 3):

Enter the number in one column (eg A), and in the next column use `DATE`:

```
=DATE(2013,12,A1)
```

Fill down to work with other rows.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a VBA macro to do this, like this:

1. Open VBA editor by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>.
2. Select from menu **Insert > Module**.
3. Write below code:

   ```
   Sub dateMe()
       On Error GoTo NotPossible
       If CInt(ActiveCell.Value) > 0 And CInt(ActiveCell.Value) < 32 Then
           ActiveCell.Value = CDate("2013-12-" + CInt(ActiveCell.Value))
       End If
   NotPossible:
   End Sub
   ```
4. Now you can open *Macro* window by selecting **View > Macros > View Macros** from menu, and now when `dateMe` is selected press **[ options... ]** and select a key for your short-cut key.

   > Note: short-cut key or running a macro over your selected cell will run after exiting from *Edit Mode* or *While Wrinting Inside Cell*.